# Map type keys to strings and then to a type of strings in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a React component that extends the Octicons icon library provided by Github at `@githubprimer/octicons-react`.

One of the library's exports is the `iconsByName` type, which looks like this:

```
type iconsByName = {
  'alert': Icon<16, 16>,
  'arrow-down': Icon<10, 16>,
  'arrow-left': Icon<10, 16>,
  'arrow-right': Icon<10, 16>,
  ...
}
```

In my component, I want to create an interface that takes in an `icon` prop and dynamically generates a list from the keys of the `iconsByName` export. In the end, my interface should look something like:

interface Octicon

```
Props {
   icon: "alert" | "arrow-down" | "arrow-left" | "arrow-right" | ...;
}
```

But I can't use `Object.keys(iconsByName)` to generate that list. How can I programmatically create a type to then pass into the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `keyof` type operator to get a union of all keys of a type:

```
type iconsByName = {
    'alert': Icon<16, 16>,
    'arrow-down': Icon<10, 16>,
    'arrow-left': Icon<10, 16>,
    'arrow-right': Icon<10, 16>,
}

interface Props {
    icon: keyof iconsByName
}
```